# Is the credit roll the same across all three games?

Tags: crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy

I've asked this question on YouTube before, but I didn't get a response. Neither Activision nor Toys for Bob have community forums. I've beaten Dr. Cortex in both Crash Bandicoot 1 and 2 in their N-Sane remakes. I've also 100%ed Spyro the Dragon and Spyro 2: Ripto's Rage. I generally watch the credits for all games at least once in order to satisfy curiosities and marvel at the number of people involved. However, at the beginning of the credits to Crash 2 and Spyro 2, I get nothing to indicate that the credits are specifically for that game. I play Nintendo Switch, and it is the norm that in collection releases on the Switch, each game in the collection retains its own credit sequence. I am not used to having a collection with the same sequence shared across all three games.

I've already figured out that the entire teams at Toys for Bob and Vicarious were responsible for porting all games in each trilogy as a group. That much is self-evident because the three games blatantly reuse core assets and models. I simply want to know if the credit sequence is hard-coded as part of the reused assets.

Answer (score 1):

I've watched them enough and I can say that *CB1* and *CB:Warped* both have the same ending, also because the "Time trial developers best times" part have all 3 games' levels listed.

The only difference I found is with *Cortex Strikes Back*, because it starts listing Toys for Bob developers:

[image]

while the other 2 games start with Vicarious Visions:

[image]

You can check yourself:

- [Crash Bandicoot ending credits](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FPn-ZRFfFpk)
- [Crash Bandicoot 2: CSB ending credits](https://youtu.be/eiZv4RnScX0?t=2401)
- [Crash Bandicoot: Warped ending credits](https://youtu.be/R3K8nvhtd3w?t=218)

But yes, the most is reused and shared across all games.